# Output characteristics of power transistors

Tags: power-electronics, fet, igbt

[image: Output characteristics for power mosfets and IGBT]

The book about electronics that I'm currently reading only briefly mentions IGBTs and power mosfets(such as the VMOS, or the HEXFET), and gives no depiction of the output characteristics. The image above is the one I found online. Is it even correct? It seems to me that they are essentially the same as for ordinary mosfets, only the gate voltages being substantially higher here since these are power devices.

Answer (score 1):

power mosfet behave like normal mosfet, but look on the datasheet on the right, power mosfet got a real high gain in current.

These devices can handle a lot of current as you can see hundreds of amp, a normal mosfet can barely handle over 500 mA. So these output stage mosfet are use to power motor and high current device.

Regards, MathieuL.

Answer (score 1):

Power MOSFETs are similar to smaller MOSFETs, just lower Rds(on), much higher capacitances and gate charge. Usually they need 10V Vgs to drive them to datasheet specifications if they are really high current.

IGBTs behave like BJTs with an insulated gate (as you might expect from the name). So they have a Vce(sat) rather than an Rds(on) so the minimum 'on' voltage at currents much lower than the rated current is higher than for a MOSFET. Generally IGBTs switch more slowly, but they can have a very attractive price/performance ratio if you need high voltage (eg. 1200V breakdown) switching at moderate speed and high current. They also need relatively high voltage Vge (usually 15V and 0 or maybe -5V) to drive them optimally. You can see in your right hand graph the Vce does not cross through the origin the same way that Vds does in the left graph.

Keep in mind that a 3V drop at 300A is almost 1kW of heat in the transistor, which is a great deal of heat to have to dispose of. The left hand graph is a MOSFET so you might say that the IGBT is clearly less efficient, but you might well find that the MOSFET is only capable of 200V Vds and the IGBT is capable of 1200V, so the percentage loss is actually considerably better for the IGBT.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the additional information. So that actually answers my original question, these graphs are correct.